# FileChooser dialog action error

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

When I open a file chooser dialog in JavaFX, whether I click the button "open" or "cancel", there is error reported:

> (java:20637): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion
>   'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

The environment I used: Kubuntu 13.10, javaFX 2.2, JDK7u45, NetBeans7.4

Thanks for telling me why? or any eventual solution~

Comment: What were you trying to choose ?

Answer (score 0):

From my little research it seems to be a bug in the OS and not in JavaFX. [Have a look here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/672089). People have been experiencing the same problem in different applications under Ubuntu environment (and I believe the same applies for Kubuntu, too).

I am on Ubuntu machine and I did run a test on `FileChooser`  to see if I had the same problem. I did not get any errors.

Try running your application on a different machine. See if the problem persists. try different architectures and different OS.

*Could you tell us what you were trying to choose?*